# Fisher–Yates Shuffle in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle, splice

New to JS and currently learning in college. For my current JS project, I am building a memory card game. I started to think on how to randomly shuffle the cards, and I got close to what Fisher–Yates Shuffle algorithm does - the second program on [this page](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/). However, I don't understand what the [0] does after the splice method exactly. Is it what shifts/compacts the array? If yes, I can't find other examples/documentations about that.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var copy = [], n = array.length, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (n) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * n--);

    // And move it to the new array.
    copy.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  }

  return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.splice(i, 1)` cuts out the `i`-th element of `array` and returns it as a single-value array (just like `array.splice(i, 2)` would cut out `i`-th and `i+1`-th element and return them as a two-element array). Then `[0]`, the simple indexing operation, picks that single element from that array (as we don't need an array); this single element is then added to `copy` using `copy.push`.

More familiar uses of the indexing operation:

```
array = [4, 7, 2, 10];
array[0]
// => 4
array[1]
// => 7

array = [18];
array[0]
// => 18
```

Comment: Thank you @Amadan!

Comment: So I put more thought into that. The thing I don't get is that, to me, the `[0]` is redundant, as we just take one element off of the array since the range of the splice is `(i, 1)`.

Comment: `splice` returns an array. `push` wants a single value. A one-element array is not the same thing as its element. It's like trying to put a mesh bag with a tomato in your blender arguing that "well, I need one tomato for this sauce, and the bag only has one tomato left in it, so why not?". You need to take the tomato out of the bag first, because those plastic mesh fibers are a bit on the chewy side.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much @Amadan

Comment: @Amadan as simple and potentially silly as it sounds, that metaphor - blending a tomato - has to be the best explanation of the difference between a single element array and the element itself that I've ever heard.  Awesome, and thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`array.splice()` returns an array, but while shuffling you want to take  a random card from an unknown position and put it inside the new array(shuffled one). Now the catch is you don't want to add the similar array again by doing `copy.push(array.splice(i, 1)` as this will add the entire returned array to copy array and the randomness of your shuffle will get reduced which in turn will cause dependent result in your game because the array will be similar(~) to last one with just few bits flipped. Adding `[0]` to `array.splice(i, 1)` ensures that you are only copying one element from the entire result array returned at time, which results in greater randomness.

Comment: Thank you @Cyclotron3x3, makes sense now. Much appreciated.

Comment: what I don't get is that the randomness is made by the random number `i`, which will pick then a random index of the array to splice, then the result will be pushed at the end of the new array `copy`, so in the end the whole indexation of the elements of the new array will be random (each iteration pushes the element at the end of the array). So isn't `[0]` redundant here?